# PHP "теряется" массив, после include файлов из Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, include

Есть простой(основной) скрипт `index.php`:

```
<?php
require 'cfg.php'; //файл с настройками
require 'langs/' . $CFG['lang'] . '.php'; // языковой файл, прописаный в файле с настройками. Языковой файл содержит фразы в виде массива
//echo 'P1>>>>>';
//var_dump($FO_LANG);
//echo '<br>';

if(file_exists($CFG['auth'])) { //если есть файл с настройками авторизации
    //echo 'P2>>>>>';
    //var_dump($FO_LANG);
    //echo '<br>';
    include $CFG['auth']; //добавить его в скрипт
    //echo 'P3>>>>>';
    //var_dump($FO_LANG);
    if ($fo_userid > 0) { //если юзерID > ноля
        echo $fo_userid; //вывести его ID
    }
    else { //если юзерID НЕ больше ноля
        var_dump ($FO_LANG['0002_fo_not_authorized']); // вывести второй элемент массива из языкового файла
    }
}
else { //если нет файла с настройками авторизации
    var_dump ($FO_LANG['0001_fo_cfg_file_not_exist']); //вывести первый элемент массива из языкового файла
}
?>
```

В дополнительном файле `langs/ru.php` как понятно, сохранены фразы, в виде массива:

```
<?php
$FO_LANG = array (
  '0001_fo_cfg_file_not_exist' => 'Не верная конфигурация.',
  '0002_fo_not_authorized' => 'Вы не авторизованы!',
);
?>
```

Файл авторизации `joomla_cfg.php`, стандартный скрипт для получения данных текущего пользователя Joomla.

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname('../.') );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();

$mainframe->route();
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$fo_userid = $user->get('id');
```

Проблема в том, что если условие `file_exists($CFG['auth'])`, оказывается ложью, то фраза корректно считывается из массива в языковом файле. А если она оказывается истинной, и происходит "подключение" данных пользователя *Joomla*, то массива в видимости не оказывается и `var_dump` выдаёт `NULL`.

Понятное дело, что можно ещё раз сделать `include` нужных файлов, но как этого избежать и правильно добавить массив, что-бы он был виден во всех случаях в пределах основного скрипта?

Файл конфигураций `cfg.php`:

```
<?php
$FO_CFG = array (
  'auth' => 'joomla_cfg.php',
  'lang' => 'ru',,
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После проведенного расследования выяснилось, что вредит строка

```
include $CFG['auth'];
```

А конкретно вызов `JRequest::clean();`, в которой происходит, дословно, следующее:

```
foreach ($GLOBALS as $key => $value){
    if ( $key != 'GLOBALS' ) {
        unset ( $GLOBALS [ $key ] );
    }
}
```

Методов борьбы несколько:

1. Инклудить, инклудить и еще раз инклудить, как завещали bad practics.
2. Разобраться, как правильно работать с Джумлой. Что-то мне подсказывает, что там есть штатные средства обеспечения многоязычности, заточенные под нее
3. Немного поменять логику приложения и вынести `include $CFG['auth'];` на самый верх.
4. Использовать для локализации не массив в глобальном неймспейсе, а класс. Как-то так:

langs/ru.php:

```
namespace langs;
class ru{
    const fo_cfg_file_not_exist = 'Не верная конфигурация.';
    const fo_not_authorized = 'Вы не авторизованы!';
}
```

index.php

```
$lang = 'langs\\'.$CFG['lang'];
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include_once str_replace('\\', '/', $class).'.php';
});    

echo $lang::fo_not_authorized;
```

Comment: _Есть уверенность, что в обоих тестовых случаях сюда приходит $CFG['lang'] === 'ru'?_
Не совсем понятен Ваш вопрос. Скорее есть уверенность, что при удачном подключении к Joomla, этот элемент массива точно не приходит))) Однако, ДО подключения, он точно есть. И точно является равным 'ru'
В _$CFG['auth']_ всего три элемента. Там нет ничего, что повлияло бы на мою проблему.
_Массив, таки, не содержит элемента 0002_fo_not_authorized_
Однозначно содержит. Ибо если подключения к Joomla не происходит, то этот элемент массива без проблем выводится.
_и посмотреть, что покажет_
Тот же NULL((

Comment: @user3543081 Вот смотрите. Сразу после `require 'langs/' . $CFG['lang'] . '.php';` массив есть. После `include $CFG['auth'];` он пропадает. Отсюда напрашивается вывод, что где-то там он переопределяется. Вангую `require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );`. Вообще, сделайте поиск слова `$FO_LANG` по всем файлам и посмотрите, где он может переопределяться.

Comment: @user3543081 вообще, такие косяки ищутся надежным дедовским методом. `var_dump($FO_LANG)` каждой второй строкой. И когда найдете точку, где он теряется - проваливайтесь дальше.

Comment: Дело в том, что массив `$FO_LANG` создан мной(для отдельной страницы) и соответственно переопределиться он нигде не может. Я дам названия всем файлам в вопросе и  добавлю туда четвёртый файл. И это будут все мои файлы с полным, на данный момент, их содержанием(я специально их очистил, чтоб оставить только имеющее отношение к проблеме содержимое). Кроме этого, в проекте есть только Joomla. И именно её код где-то "съедает" мой массив. Однако полагая, что проблема типичная именно для Joomla,  надеялся, что подскажут именно Joomlaводы...

Comment: @user3543081 ну вы же понимаете, что чудес не бывает и сама собой джумла не будет уничтожать ваших массивов? Не приписывайте ей дьявольских козней. Вам достаточно в трех местах написать `var_dump($FO_LANG);` для того, что бы локализовать проблему в `index.php`. Всего то 3 строки, а какая экономия времени и нервов. Я вам даже сейчас эти строки добавлю в вопрос, в виде комментариев.

Comment: Спасибо, что пытаетесь помочь! Конечно же я пробовал это делать. И дело в том, что массив исчезает сразу после `include $CFG['auth'];` Я снова подправил вопрос и вот что получил на выходе: http://savepic.net/8675302.jpg

Comment: в таком случае имеет смысл идти дольше и добавить тот-же var_dump в $CFG['auth'].  Я там выше Ванговал про require_once. Кстати, почему именно `FO_`?

Comment: `FO_` как раз для того, что-бы не перепутать ни с чем другим. Аббревиатура моего "детища" )) Вообщем, проследил я цепочку по Вашему совету... есть в недрах Joomla такая функция `JRequest::clean();`, с очень красноречивым именем. Находится она в файле libraries\joomla\import.php. Вот она то и убивает мой массив. Поищу конечно где её корни... но думаю, что наверное всё-же придётся просто ещё раз сделать `include`...

Comment: Собственно да https://docs.joomla.org/API15:JRequest/clean. Там очищаются ВСЕ переменные глобальной области видимости. Какой то адок. Но есть решение более изящное, нежели постоянные импорты. Обновлю ответ минут через 15.